# Passing a long array of elements as parameters in a Symfony redirect after form validation

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form in which a user can upload a CSV file containing emails. Those emails get processed and sent, and for the ones that passes the validation I create an array of "$successfulEmails".

In my first implementation I passed that to a twig rendering it, and it was ok (I could display in my twig "These are the emails that were sent" with the list following). The only issue is that in the landing page I could hit the refresh button, resubmitting the form. So, as suggested in Symfony documentation, it's preferrable to have a redirect at the end of the form->isValid(). The problem with redirect is that it goes through Symfony's routing system: I can pass a few variables doing something like

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('name_of_the_route', array('param1' => $param1Value, 'param2' => $param2Value, )));
```

And that would generate the url with all the parameters (and values) in it.

But AFAIK I don't have the possibility of passing an array like the one I need (maybe containing 100 emails).

I was thinking about using a flash message and create a mega string with all the emails, comma separated. It's far from elegant (and is there a limit to the length of the flash message?).

Any other solution?

Thank you!

Comment: consider to store the array in session only for passing data, then you can remove

Answer (score 0):

To get around the "can't pass an array" problem you could concatenate the email addresses into a single string delimited by something that doesn't occur in an email address. Maybe a pipe character |.

The bigger issue you have is that 100 emails joined together is probably too much to comfortably put in the query string. You should probably save them on the server somewhere.  Two ideas come to mind.

- Save the array in session.  That's the quick and simple way and would probably work okay although session is not really intended for lots of data.
- Save in a database. The simplest way I can think of is to have a table with an id and a big text or blob column. Serialize the array of email addresses, save them in the text column and redirect. You could use a Doctrine entity instead of the database directly. You have several choices of how to pass the id to the redirected action. Passing it as a single query parameter would work but if you do that and it's a simple integer id then users will be able to change the number and see the lists for other users. You could fix that by adding a random string or number in another column and pass that as another query parameter. The query in the redirected action then uses both to retrieve the list.

Comment: Thank you. Another solution would be to implement a table in a DB with unique strings of submitted forms, and when the form gets processed I kill the record. If you try a resubmit it tells you "the form has already been submitted". This way I solve the problem in other areas of the application also, where I need to pass objects and not simple arrays.